# Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Full_Stack_Development\Projects\StudyPurpose\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon, node-mongodb-native, grunt-nodemon

I'm a beginner to node.js/express, I created a sample project and when i tried running the project/server through nodemon it shows error(I've done another project before and it worked fine).

I have tried re-installing the nodemon, even tried installing it again globally. Nothing seems to be working. But, when i run my older project it still works fine.
Deleted my current project and did it again from scratch but the same issue triggers again and again.
running the project as `node app.js` works.

I've changed the

```
"start": "node app.js"
```

to

```
"start": "nodemon app.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you check if the directory is correct? and in the given path the file exists. You can also check after updating node. and if you have found the solution do comment in detail.

Comment: D:\Full_Stack_Development\Projects\StudyPurpose\Backend_&_DB\sample1 
The above is my real path of the file. But I don't know why node is re-routing to a path which is not present. 
And the problem occurs only to this particular folder which I mentioned. I've done another project on another folder and it works well. 
Ofcourse I've tried updating the node re-installed it, even globally.

Now I'm doing my project on another folder. 

Still if anyone knows why it is or have any solutions, that would be helpful, 'cause I need to know why it is showing this error.